# Adding Many to Many Data Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Case: I have 2 tables; one for **users** and one for **assignments**. A user can have many assignments and an assignment can be assigned to many users. I have a form in the frontend to add assignment and assign the users for the assignment and I am really confused on how to add the assignment and user to the joint table '**user_assignment**'. Can someone point where I am having the mistake? Also for this, I refer to [Advanced M:N Associations](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html).

I also attach my code for the **Users** and **Assignments** model, and other relevant code parts.

**user.model.js**

```
 module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define("users", {
    firstName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    department: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    role: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  });
  return User;
};
```

**assignment.model.js**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Assignment = sequelize.define("assignments", {
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    department: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    urgency: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    assignmentBegin: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    assignmentEnd: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  });
  return Assignment;
};
```

**database/index.js**

```
...
db.user = require("../models/user.model")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.assignment = require("../models/assignment.model")(sequelize, Sequelize);
...
db.user.belongsToMany(db.assignment, {
  through: "user_assignment",
  as: "assignments",
  foreignKey: "userId",
});

db.assignment.belongsToMany(db.user, {
  through: "user_assignment",
  as: "users",
  foreginKey: "assignmentId",
});
...
```

**assignment.controller.js**

```
const db = require("../database");
const Assignment = db.assignment;
const User = db.user;

exports.create = async (req, res) => {
  const {
    participant,
    title,
    department,
    urgency,
    assignmentBegin,
    assignmentEnd,
    description,
  } = req.body;

  await Assignment.create({
    title: title,
    department: department,
    urgency: urgency,
    assignmentBegin: assignmentBegin,
    assignmentEnd: assignmentEnd,
    description: description
  }).then(async result => {
    for (i = 0; i < participant.length; i++) {
      const user = await User.findByPk(participant[i])
      // console.log(user.id)
      await UserController.addAssignment(user.id, result.id);
      // await UserController.addAssignment(2, 1)
    }
  }).catch(err => {
    res.json({ message: "ERROR WHILE CREATING ASSIGNMENT!" });
    console.log(">>> ERROR WHILE CREATING ASSIGNMENT!")
  });
}
```

Any pointers on what I should do would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you define the model associations inside each of the model files. Also you should hash/encrypt your passwords before saving them to the DB, you can use the .comparePassword() function outside of the model in a controller when logging in etc.

**models/User.js**

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')
const bcrypt = Promise.promisifyAll(require('bcrypt'))

function hashPassword (user) {
    const SALT_FACTOR = 12

    if (!user.changed('password')) {
        return;
    } else {
        user.setDataValue('password', bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, SALT_FACTOR))
    }
}

module.exports = User = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const User = sequelize.define('User', {
        firstName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        lastName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        department: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        role: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        {
        hooks: {
            beforeCreate: hashPassword,
            beforeUpdate: hashPassword
        }
    })

    User.associate = models => {
        User."Association type here"(models."Model to associate",
            {Options (For many to many add your "through" table here)}
        )
        // Example:
        User.belongsToMany(models.Assignment, {
            through: "UserAssignment"
        })
    }

    User.prototype.comparePassword = function (password) {
        return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password)
    }

    return User
}
```

And in the associated Model (**models/Assignment.js**):

```
module.exports = Assignment = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Assignment = sequelize.define('Assignment', {
        title: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        department: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        urgency: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        assignmentBegin: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        assignmentEnd: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        description: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: false
    })

    Assignment.associate = models => {
        Assignment.belongsToMany(models.User, { 
            through: "UserAssignment"
        })
    }

    return Role
}
```

The joint table (**models/UserAssignment.js**):

```
module.exports = UserAssignment = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const UserAssignment = sequelize.define('UserAssignment', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
            primaryKey: true
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: false
    })

    return UserAssignment
}
```

And finally my index.js file (**models/index.js**), it programatically adds the models to the DB:

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0)
    && (file !== basename)
    && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

As an extra note, you can shorten down your createAssignment function in your controller by doing this instead:

```
const {
    participant,
    title,
    department,
    urgency,
    assignmentBegin,
    assignmentEnd,
    description,
} = req.body;

await Assignment.create({
    title: title,
    department: department,
    urgency: urgency,
    assignmentBegin: assignmentBegin,
    assignmentEnd: assignmentEnd,
    description: description
    }).then(async result => {
        result.addUsers(participant)
    }).catch(err => {
        res.json({ message: "ERROR WHILE CREATING ASSIGNMENT!" });
        console.log(">>> ERROR WHILE CREATING ASSIGNMENT!")
    });
```

Hope this helps, if not lmk ill try to help some more.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I forgot to add the json data for the assignment form; the participant is in an array form and  I looped it before addUsers. I would like to ask, when I changed my models to the way you suggested, somehow it does not associate both models as many to many. I do think that it would be much better to use your way but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Yeah thats my bad, its because my index file is pretty different to yours and I have other files ouside of it that its fetching and using. I can rewrite it to fit your file https://pastebin.com/cSwJUqA4. This should work, just make sure to to have the index.js file inside of the same folder as your models. If you need more help, message me on discord Rami#2145 would be easier for me.

Comment: please dont feel bad, I appreciate your help! Thank you for spending your time helping me.